# custom post type: own database table structure and custom "new-post" interface

Tags: custom-post-types, database, admin-ui

I was tried to search answer to my question, but I didn't find.

What I need:

1. Make own post type. It's simple with Custom Post Type UI plugin. **Solved.**
2. To have own table in DB for post of new type. When I create custom post type, all data of created posts writes to default wordpress tables in DB and I want to change it. **Not solved.**
3. To have own interface for creating new post in my custom post type. Clicking on "Add new 'customtype' post" gives me standart interface for creating standart posts. Name, tags, categories and post body to fill. I want to change it too, with my own form (Name, date, place, some checkboxes and dropdown selects). **Not solved.**

I will very appreciate any help or words to google and learn.

P.S. I know, Im not good in english. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not a Custom Post Type and what you want (or think you want) is not a custom post type. To push a CPT to its own separate table you'd have to interrupt core processes in a hundred places, and I am not even sure there are hooks enough to do that.

What you describing is a rebuild of the Custom Post Type system-- a duplication of functionality, a second post system in parallel. That is a lot of work.

If you must have your pseudo-CPT in another table, ditch the Core system entirely and start from nothing. It will be less painful.

You've solved issue #1. If you are willing to forgo issue #2, issue #3 is also fairly easily solved in a couple of ways.

1. Most of the meta boxes on a CPT edit page are replaceable, and
   certain elements can be removed when the CPT is registered, or
   removed latter with [`remove_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support). You can keep
   the GUI but modify it to match your requirements.
2. You can [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) with `'show_in_menu' => false` and
   build a form from scratch elsewhere on the back-end.

Comment: Many plugins uses own db tabkes, if I create own plugin, which adds custom post type, can it be possible - to make publish to own table? To be honest, I try to create some kind of 'events' system, where users will create own events and table in db will contain non-typical rows, that's why default post table is not good for me.

Thanks for other answers.

Comment: Yes, many plugins do use their own tables. I never said not to use your own tables, though I question the wisdom of doing so in this case. What I said was that you are not really talking about a custom post type once you hijack most everything about custom post types and that you are better off using a CPT as it was meant to be used or not using a CPT at all and building your own system.